# eclipse file explorer pull a file, can't open file in windows "file in use"

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to write android apps in java.  I used Eclipse file explorer to "pull a file from the device" on to my desktop.  (All this on a Windows 7 Enterprise laptop).

When I go to open the file on my windows desktop, usually, but not quite always, it says I can't open the file because the file "is in use by another application and cannot be accessed."

Anybody know how I fix this?  How I get access consistently to files I have pulled with eclipse file explorer > pull file without having to quit and restart eclipse constant? (Quitting eclipse does work.)

Comment: Lots of people find it more efficient to use adb pull from the command line.  Can't promise that will solve your problem, but it's at least worth a shot.  You can use adb shell to find what you want.

Comment: I must wait some time: about 10-15 sec.